# Joomla sql inner join query does not work?

Tags: php, sql, join, joomla

I have an SQL query that works nicely in phpMyAdmin, but I'm unable to make it work thru the Joomla API. Here is my Joomla code:

```
    $myid = 17;
    $query->select($db->qn('MESSAGE.ID','MESSAGE.ID'));
    $query->select($db->qn('MESSAGE.INQUIRY_ID','MESSAGE.INQUIRY_ID'));
    $query->select($db->qn('INQUIRY.ID','INQUIRY.ID'));
    $query->from($db->qn('MESSAGE'));
    $query->innerJoin($db->qn('INQUIRY'));
    $query->on($db->qn('MESSAGE.INQUIRY_ID') . ' = ' . $db->qn('INQUIRY.ID'));
    $query->where($db->qn('MESSAGE.ID') . ' = ' . $db->quote($myid));
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $msg = $db->loadObjectList();
    var_dump($msg);exit();
```

And here is what I got, from the dump:

```
array(4) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#787 (3) { ["MESSAGE.ID"]=> string(2) "17" 
**["MESSAGE.INQUIRY_ID"]=> string(1) "5" ["INQUIRY.ID"]=> string(1) "2"** } 
[1]=> object(stdClass)#788 (3) { ["MESSAGE.ID"]=> string(2) "17" 
["MESSAGE.INQUIRY_ID"]=> string(1) "5" ["INQUIRY.ID"]=> string(1) "3" } 
[2]=> object(stdClass)#789 (3) { ["MESSAGE.ID"]=> string(2) "17" 
["MESSAGE.INQUIRY_ID"]=> string(1) "5" ["INQUIRY.ID"]=> string(1) "4" } 
[3]=> object(stdClass)#790 (3) { ["MESSAGE.ID"]=> string(2) "17" 
["MESSAGE.INQUIRY_ID"]=> string(1) "5" ["INQUIRY.ID"]=> string(1) "5" } }
```

My understanding of the "inner join" is that only those records should be joined where the MESSAGE.INQUIRY_ID and INQUIRY.ID field are identical. This does not seem to be the case in the dump (see the bold).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot, 
W.

Comment: You should first check what is the output of the query using `echo $query->dump();` method and see what is the difference with the actual query.

Comment: Thanks, your advice immediately solved my problem! Looking at the query object I could see that the "ON" part of the JOIN expression is not there. The reason was that the query object does not have an independent "ON" method. Strange that I got no error message, but adding the "ON" part to the "JOIN" expression solved my problem. Thanks again! W.

Comment: good to know, I have also added an answer for the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using query builder you can use `echo $query->dump();` the method to check the final query and compare it with you working query.

As you said, in your case, the issue was with `on` method, which does not exist and your query was not as you were expecting.